# Android. Espresso. How to test custom view in custom adapter?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-listview, android-adapter, android-espresso

I use Espresso library in my project. In tutorial and samples have examples how to test adapter and view. But I have custom adapter and custom specific view.
My view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCity"
    style="@style/Widget.TextView.OnlyOneLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/ab_city_spinner_inner_padding"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="@color/ab_city_spinner_city_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ab_city_spinner_city_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRegion"
    style="@style/Widget.TextView.OnlyOneLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/ab_city_spinner_inner_padding"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="@color/ab_city_spinner_region_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ab_city_spinner_region_text_size" /></LinearLayout>
```

My test:

```
@SmallTest
public void testChangeCity()
{
    onView(withId(R.id.spAB)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    onView(allOf(withText("City1"), hasSibling(withText("Test")))).perform(ViewActions.click());
}
```

It's work. But I don't now what data have view. Haw can I open Spinner and click for item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find answer.
Find and click on Spinner

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers?.withId(R.id.spAB)).perform(ViewActions?.click());
```

Take data for Spinner

```
List<City> listCity = getActivity().getCityList();
```

Check data

```
Preconditions.checkNotNull(listCity, "No have any city");
```

Than click it view

```
ViewMatchers?.hasSibling(ViewMatchers?.withText(listCity.get(0).getName())))).perform(ViewActions?.click());
```

Comment: So much of your code is missing - for example, where is getCityList defined?